# Show bestsellers product in home page

Tags: best-seller

I want to show best sellers products in home page, I searched about it and use [**this solution**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288503/how-to-show-latest-top-rated-and-best-products-in-left-bar-in-magento). It's worked so good but now I have 2 problems:

1-Product displays on what basis? And If I want to show best sellers in month what am I do?

2-When I added `<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true, '-new') ?>` in my code to show price of product, it was show just price of simple product and grouped product's price doesn't show!! How can I fix it?

Comment: visit  link:-http://inchoo.net/magento/bestseller-products-in-magento/

Comment: @AshvinMonpara: I saw this link but I don't understand that  `class Inchoo_Damir_Block_Bestsellers` should write where?

Comment: link:-http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/best-seller-extension-with-product-ribbons.html

Comment: @AshvinMonpara: thanks for link but I don't want to install an extension and I want to do it with write codes.